# How to make dynamic uitabbar controllers?(swift)

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

I make an app that has 3 tabs. I want to make my tab bar controller dynamically change the view controller of the first tab bar according to the logged in user type. The rest two tab bars are static. For example, if the user type is 1, I want to show *ViewController1* for the first tab, and if the user type is 2, I want to show *ViewController2* instead. Is this impossible to achieve when the tab bar is designed in the storyboard? I use storyboard in the app.

Comment: Configure tabbar by code or create two separate tabbar controllers in storyboard , use their restoration id or storyboard id to present specific navigation.

Comment: I edited my question, hence, I don't want to duplicate two of my static tabs if possible. I want to know if this is possible using storyboard, doing it by code would be my worst case scenario. Thanks.

Comment: Simply NO as you specify VC in each tab in storyboard then how you expect to change it later without doing anything?

Comment: Ok then I would ask if it is possible to design two of my view controllers in the storyboard and set one of them for the first tab bar initially and change it dynamically to the second VC when necessary using storyboard id etc?

Answer (score 4):

You can change these by using  the function on a tabview controller setviewcontrollers (see documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621177-setviewcontrollers).

For instance I have a storyboard with 4 Viewcontrollers in a tabviewcontroller, and then in the first viewController that loads, I added the following in viewDidLoad()"

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "myStoryboard", bundle: nil)
let newTab = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "testControllerID") as! TestViewController
let myControllers = [newTab, tabButton2, tabButton3, self, tabButton4]
tabBarController?.setViewControllers(myControllers, animated: true)
```

So I was able to rearrange my previously defined tabs as well as add "newTab", which is a VC designed on the storyboard, given an identifier, but not actually added to the tabViewController.

Hope that helps